# Page system in back end or front end

Tags: php, mysql, performance, angular

I want make a page system to a data base values, what is correct?

1-) Get all values of backend and create a page system with front end.

2-) Get only values that will be show in select page on back end?

My concern is with website performance

I'm using Angular in front, php on back end, and MySql database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the option 2 because:

- You won´t have in your front end data that you don´t need
- Your front end will use less memory (as you have less data)
- You will have less data to comunicate
- You will have less security problems
- Your front end will be faster

  ......

Well, i think that if you don´t need the data in your front end, just don´t send it